# Having issues to do comments on questions

Tags: support, comments

I'm having troubles for commenting questions/posts. When clicking "add comment" it goes to the top of the page instead of opening the text box.

I was able to do so, don't know when started to fail. I do have +50 reputation on the communities that I'm trying to comment in.

Comment: Something on your end is most likely blocking required JS files. Open your browsers developer tools (usually F12 key), go to Network tab, reload, and see what is blocked.

Comment: Additionally check if http://cdn.sstatic.net is blocked.

Comment: Often this happens to me when the internet gives out. Try disconnecting and re-connecting to wifi.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions!  I will try to do some debug on my end to see what is happening.